# How to evaluate the integral: $\int_0^\infty\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\sin(2\beta x)}{x}\mathrm dx$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm trying to calculate the following integral:
$$ \int_0^\infty\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}\sin(2\beta x)}{x}\mathrm dx, $$
where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions). My first step was:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\int_n^{n+1}\frac{\sin(2\beta x)}{x}\mathrm dx $$
Since $\displaystyle \int_n^{n+1}\frac{\sin(2\beta x)}{x}\mathrm dx =\text{Si}(2\beta(n+1))-\text{Si}(2\beta n)$, where $\text{Si}(z)$ is the [Sine Integral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineIntegral.html). Then we have the sum:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\left[\text{Si}(2\beta(n+1))-\text{Si}(2\beta n) \right] $$
Here is my problem, I have no idea how to calculate this sum. Perhaps the sum does not fit in terms of Sine Integral, I tried to take the sum into the integral before obtaining Sine Integral, but I was not successful. I will be grateful for help.

Comment: It should be: $$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor } \sin (2 \beta  x)}{x} \, dx=\text{Si}(2 \beta )+\sum
   _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^n (\text{Si}(2 \beta  (n+1))-\text{Si}(2 \beta  n))$$

Comment: as $\beta\to\infty$ integral tends to $\pi/2$

Answer (score 3):

$$I(\beta)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\Big[\text{Si}(2\beta(n+1))-\text{Si}(2\beta n) \Big]$$
$$I'(\beta)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\Big[2 (n+1) \text{sinc}(2 \beta  (n+1))-2 n \text{sinc}(2 \beta  n)\Big]$$
Given by a CAS
$$I'(\beta)=\frac{\tan (\beta )-\sin (3 \beta ) \sec (\beta )}{2 \beta }$$
$$I(\beta)=\int\frac{\tan (\beta )-\sin (3 \beta ) \sec (\beta )}{2 \beta }\, d\beta$$ As far as I can see, there is no closed form for the antiderivative.

If $\beta < \frac \pi 2$, we could make a series expansion around $\beta=0$
$$\frac{\tan (\beta )-\sin (3 \beta ) \sec (\beta )}{2 \beta }=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n 2^{2n+1}\frac{E_{2 n+1}(-1)+1}{(2n+1)!}\, \beta^{2n}$$
$$I(\beta)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n 2^{2n+1}\frac{E_{2 n+1}(-1)+1}{(2n+1)^2\,(2n)!}\, \beta^{2n+1}$$

Limiting the summation to $1000$ terms, some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\beta & \text{summation} & \text{integration} \\
 0.1 & -0.0994447100 & -0.0994447100 \\
 0.2 & -0.1955639426 & -0.1955639426 \\
 0.3 & -0.2850622742 & -0.2850622742 \\
 0.4 & -0.3646983033 & -0.3646983033 \\
 0.5 & -0.4312954393 & -0.4312954393 \\
 0.6 & -0.4817299506 & -0.4817299506 \\
 0.7 & -0.5128815984 & -0.5128815984 \\
 0.8 & -0.5215216327 & -0.5215216325 \\
 0.9 & -0.5040901387 & -0.5040901367 \\
 1.0 & -0.4562617463 & -0.4562617462 \\
 1.1 & -0.3720624328 & -0.3720624322 \\
 1.2 & -0.2418977415 & -0.2418977414 \\
 1.3 & -0.0474073540 & -0.0474073533 
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

I suppose that you will not need too much terms since it is an alternating series. Checking for $\beta=1$ and writing
$$I(1)=\sum_{n=0}^p (-1)^n 2^{2n+1}\frac{E_{2 n+1}(-1)+1}{(2n+1)^2\,(2n)!}+\sum_{n=p+1}^\infty (-1)^n 2^{2n+1}\frac{E_{2 n+1}(-1)+1}{(2n+1)^2\,(2n)!}$$
$$R_p=\Bigg|\frac{2^{2 p+3} (E_{2 p+3}(-1)+1)}{(2 p+3)^2 \Gamma (2 p+3)}\Bigg|$$

Computed for $10 \leq p \leq 100$, a quick and dirty regression
$$\log(R_p)=a+b\, p$$ gives (with $R^2=0.999994$)
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & -4.54337 & 0.03703 & \{-4.61696,-4.46978\} \\
 b & -0.92421 & 0.00061 & \{-0.92541,-0.92300\} \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Very nice approach, sir @ClaudeLeibovici! This is clearer now, but do you think there is a closed form to the original problem? Any better approach than mine?

Comment: Your steps are satisfactory to me for sure! I just thought my approach was making it difficult to find a closed shape, that's all. Merry Christmas to you and a happy new year! lol

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Notice that as $\beta$ increases $I(\beta)$ tends to $\pi/2$. I have a *mirabilis demonstratio* but this space is to little...